# If equals or greather than 3 rows

Tags: sql-server, razor, asp.net-webpages

I'm trying to make a review section, but I only want it to show if there's 3 or more reviews posted.

When I do this I just seem to get an error.

```
@{
  var reviewCount = db.Query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM Reviews");
}

@if (reviewCount >= 3)
{
    <section class="col-md-12 reviews">
        <h2>Anmeldelser</h2>
        @foreach (var row in db.Query("SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Reviews ORDER BY DateTime"))
        {
            <article class="col-md-4">
                <p>" @row.Text "</p> <p>- @row.FirstName @row.LastName</p>
            </article>
        }
    </section>
}
```

Comment: What kind of an error?

Comment: It's in Danish, but it says something like; "The operator >= can't be used with operands of the types "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<dynamic>" and "int"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a single value returned from your database operation, you should use the `QueryValue` method instead of `Query`. The first returns a scalar value whereas the second returns a collection of `DynamicRecord` objects.

```
@{
  var reviewCount = db.QueryValue("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM Reviews");
}

@if (reviewCount >= 3){
    ...
```